# How to fix 'window.innerHeight' giving different values for the same device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a mobile-only site and I'm aiming to display some content in a specific and the same place no matter what device / screen-size a user has.

The user's screen width/height is detected with JavaScript, then those values are used in an equation to calculate how far down to place the content (to ensure it's the same place on each device). This site also has the meta tags `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` and `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` to allow users to save the site to their home-screen and display it as an app (without the browser features like the URL bar).

When the site is opened through this method as a home-screen shortcut/app on my iPhone 13 Pro Max, the content is displayed at the perfect height, but when opened in the Safari browser, the content is displayed in a different place, as if different values were given for the height and width even though it's the same device. Weird and similar behaviour has occurred when tested on a Samsung Galaxy S10+.

I tested this on my iPhone by logging the values detected for the screen height in the Safari browser and also as a home-screen shortcut/app. For Safari (content displayed in the WRONG place), the value was `746`px, but for the home-screen shortcut/app (content displayed in the CORRECT place) the value was `879`px. **Why are these different values for the same screen and how could this be fixed?**

Here's the relevant HTML, CSS and JS code if it helps, and yes, I'm new to JavaScript, you can probably tell:

```
<style>.element { position: absolute; }</style>

<img class="element" src="content.png">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var one = height / width;
    var two = 10.5 / one;
    var html = document.querySelector(".element");
    html.style.top = two + "%";
</script>
```

I tried to make this question as clear as possible, apologies if it's still confusing. Thanks!

Comment: What value are the getting for the width on each browser?

Comment: @Makaze the width seems to function properly and is the same / doesn't have this issue. From my tests on my iPhone it was `428`px on both the app and in Safari.

Comment: What about outerHeight value? The only difference I can think of is the presence of the navigation controls in the browser app itself.

Comment: InnerHeight is not the height of the screen.  It’s the amount of available vertical space in the part of the browser used to display web pages, so that will vary from browser to browser.  See [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)

Comment: See: [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)